# Как скопировать строку из одного метода в другой

Tags: java, методы

У меня есть два класса, один из которых main. В последнем хранится переменная Name. Что нужно сделать, чтобы передать её значение другой переменной в другом классе?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 String name = new String();
 name = "Игорь";
}
```

И в другом классе

```
public class qq {
    String  Name2 = ????;
}
```

Что какой код должен быть на месте знаков вопроса, чтобы name перенести в Name2?
    Долго ищу ответ и никак не могу найти. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант со статической переменной уже привели, привожу вариант с переменной экземпляра класса. set и get методы нужны , что бы не нарушать инкапсуляцию.

```js
public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
 String name = new String();
 name = "Игорь";
 
 qq a = new qq();
 a.setName(name);
 System.out.println(a.getName());
}
}
class qq{
private String Name2;

public void setName(String name){
Name2 = name;
}

public String getName(){
return Name2;
}
}
```

Если класс внутренний, т.е. в вашем случае внутри класса, где main.

```js
public class qew {
public static void main(String[] args) {
 String name = new String();
 name = "Игорь";
 
 qew q = new qew();
 qq a = q.new qq();
 a.setName(name);
 System.out.println(a.getName());

}
public class qq{
private String Name2;

public void setName(String name){
Name2 = name;
}

public String getName(){
return Name2;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Смотря для чего это требуется, если переменную менять не придется, тогда можно объявить ее `Static`

```
public class Qq {
Static String  name2 = "Test";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
String name = new String();
 name = Qq.name2;
}
```

Обратите внимание, что имена классов должны быть с заглавной буквы, и имена переменной наоборот, все строчными

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ClassWithName {
    String name = "Игорь"; // name на уровне класса, ибо в main он не видим
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // String name = "Игорь"; тут его scope (область видимости) ограничена main
    }
}

class qq extends ClassWithName{ // наследуем всё из класса ClassWithName
    String  Name2 = name; // String name = "Игорь"; записываем его в Name2
}
```